# Как в реакт-компоненте получить класс элемента из evt.target при клике на document

Tags: javascript, reactjs

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import { useDispatch, useSelector } from 'react-redux';
import { changeSortType } from '../../store/action';
import { AppDispatch, State } from '../../types/state';
import { SORT_TYPES } from '../../const';

function SortOffers(): JSX.Element {
  const [activeClass, setActiveClass] = useState<string>('');
  const currentSortType = useSelector<State>((store) => store.sortType);
  const dispatch = useDispatch<AppDispatch>();

  const toggleActiveClass = () => {
    if (activeClass) {
      setActiveClass('');
    } else {
      setActiveClass('places__options--opened');
    }
  };

  document.addEventListener('click', (evt) => {
    console.log(evt.currentTarget); // Как здесь получить className
  });

  return (
    <form className="places__sorting" action="#" method="get">
      <span className="places__sorting-caption">Sort by</span>
      <span onClick={toggleActiveClass} className="places__sorting-type" tabIndex={0}>
        {`${currentSortType}`}
        <svg className="places__sorting-arrow" width="7" height="4">
          <use xlinkHref="#icon-arrow-select"></use>
        </svg>
      </span>
      <ul className={`places__options places__options--custom ${activeClass}`}>
        {SORT_TYPES.map((sortType) => (
          <li
            onClick={(evt) => {
              toggleActiveClass();
              dispatch(changeSortType(evt.currentTarget.textContent));
            }}
            className={`places__option ${currentSortType === sortType ? 'places__option--active' : ''}`}
            key={sortType}
            tabIndex={0}
          >
            {sortType}
          </li>
        ))}
      </ul>
    </form>
  );
}

export default SortOffers;
```

Есть вот такой компонент. В нём есть выпадающий список с сортировкой - `` ul className={`places__options places__options--custom ${activeClass}`}> `` Если этот список открыт, то при клике МИМО этого списка, нужно его закрыть, убрав активный класс. Я хочу ловить клик на всём `document`-е и с помощью `evt.target.className` узнавать был клик по этому списку или МИМО него. Проблема в том что `evt.target` в данном случае не содержит в себе свойство **className**. Также не помогло использование `evt.currentTarget`.

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bjavascript%5D+%D0%BA%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%BA+%D0%B2%D0%BD%D0%B5+

Answer (score 0):

Пока сделал так:

```
document.addEventListener('click', (evt) => {
    const evtTarget = evt.target as HTMLElement;
    if (evtTarget.className !== 'places__sorting-type' &&
        evtTarget.className !== 'places__option' &&
        activeClass === 'places__options--opened') {
      toggleActiveClass();
    }
});
```

Явно переопределять тип как `HTMLElement` вроде как плохая практика, но код работает и это главное.

Comment: Ваш ответ можно улучшить с помощью дополнительной информации. Пожалуйста, нажмите [edit] для добавления подробностей, например, цитат или документации, чтобы другие могли подтвердить правильность вашего ответа. Вы можете найти дополнительную информацию о том, как писать хорошие ответы [в Справке](/help/how-to-answer).